# Set gmail vacation response with python

Tags: python, google-api, gmail, google-api-python-client

I'm using python to talk to gmail. My question is whether is there a way to programmatically set the vacation response or not. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Google Apps accounts, you can use the [Email Settings API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/email-settings/) to [set signatures for users](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/email-settings/#manage_vacation-responder_settings). This API does not work with @gmail.com accounts or free Google Apps domains.